# Edit: What is it when old unix tools fail sometimes?

Tags: bash, shell

ls and find have not worked at times. For example, some days ago:

```
ls wo_*scr
```

didn't work. Eventually I renamed the wo_*scr file to tmp, and renamed it back to the original. Then ls wo_*scr worked. Isn't that strange?

Today,

```
find mydir -iname *scr
```

didn't show anything (even with escaping). But *py or *src did.

Lately I have installed a lot of software with apt-get, pip, npm, and git, and scripts from trusted origin (like anaconda from continuum.io). Can typical new software drive the system mad? Too much for a laptop? Ubuntu fails sometimes and I should reinstall it????

About my system:

OS: I'm using Ubuntu in my laptop (Description: Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS; Release: 14.04. Architecture: x86-64 (64 bit)).

About filesystem, permisions, and all: I work from my home directory. I am the only user, and I create regular files. Some of them I make executable (to perform simple things like changing names of files).

Comment: Please add an example of a case where `ls` is not working (copy-paste from the terminal), also add output of `ls` (without any patter-matching).

Comment: Thanks for having a look. Now I think I have simply overloaded the laptop. There's no more more mystery to what I coded than this:    

`$ ls wo_*_*scr
$ ls: cannot access wo_*_*scr: No such file or directory`

`$find /home -iname *scr
$                                    `

And those outputs are bad. If it keeps happening, I guess I'll try to reinstall everything :-( (well, a bit less than everything)

Comment: You did not add the output of a simple `ls` (in the same directory) without any argument. That would be the interesting part...

Comment: `ls` without any argument would output all of the files correctly. The problem has to do with modifying scripts stored in the PATH, as it happened again today. I have a script that tests if `$file` exists, where `file=\`ls wo_*_*scr 2>/dev/null\``. After modifying the script, the test failed, and ls in the cli failed as well for that particular pattern-matching expression. On a separate occasion without scripting involved, `find` failed  with the particular expression *scr. And I posted how ls and find were behaving badly. I don't know how normal/abnormal these sort of problems are.

Answer (score 3):

The `*` will be expanded by the shell. You should quote it like:

```
find mydirectory -iname '*scr'
```

or

```
find mydirectory -iname \*scr
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But I wasn't clear enough that my problem is a strange behaviour: *scr didn't work. *src (and others) did. (One single .scr, out of many, was indeed found. Besides, of course I had already tried to escape the *). I mean: find sometimes is not working ok, like the other day ls wasn't working.  I was guessing there's something "wrong with the system".

Comment: You could give us detailed information about your system and the directories/files (OS, filesystem, owner, groups, ACLs, etc.), then maybe someone can help you. Just keep in mind that `find` and `ls` are really old unix tools and it would be very surprising if you hit a bug on these tools.